# IPv6 firewall problem with ps4

Tags: ipv6

I'm experiencing a problem with my router cisco d3928 and codww2 online.

I opened all the ports needed to play codww2 online and nothing worked, but if i disable ipv6 firewall i can play normally.

What should I do? It is safe to play with ipv6 firewall disabled?

Comment: Generally you should not disable _any_ part of your firewall.

Comment: How to configure your firewall rules to make a program work is more of a question of the progam's support.